# Bounded and Not Bounded with Linear Operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $T:X \to Y $be a linear operator between two normed spaces X and Y. Show that if for any sequence ${x_{n}}\subseteq X$, ${x_{n}} \to 0$ implies $Tx_{n}$ is bounded,then T is bounded.

My solution:
By contraposition if T is not bounded, then $Tx_{n}$  is not bounded implies for some sequence ${x_{n}}\subseteq X$, ${x_{n}} \to 0$ .

We know that if T is not bounded,then for all $\epsilon>0, \sup||Tx||=\infty$

I dont know how proceed solution help me please?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $T$ is not bounded. Then there exists a sequence $(y_n)$ such that

$$
\frac{\|Ty_n\|}{\|y_n\|} \to \infty \text{ as } n\to\infty
$$

Take
$$
x_n = \frac{y_n}{ \|y_n\|^{1/2} \|T y_n\|^{1/2} }
$$

Then $x_n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$ since $\|x_n\| = (\|y_n\|/\|T y_n\|)^{1/2} \to 0$ and

$$
\| Tx_n \| = \left( \frac{\|T y_n\|}{\|y_n\|} \right)^{1/2} \to \infty \mbox{ as }n\to\infty.
$$

Comment: Could you elaborate why $x_n \to 0$? I don't see it clearly and it is probably something trivial.

Comment: @НикитаВасильев I believe there was a mistake in the example, which I believe is now fixed.